# Solr Index : Parent / Child documents

Tags: solr, solrj

I'm using Solr to index some contents but currently, theses contents are suposed to be parent / child related.

I'm having something like that:

```
<doc>
  <id>*an Id*</id>
  <path>*a path*</path>
  <title>*a title*</title>
  <type>**Page**</type>
</doc>
<doc>
  <id>*an other Id*</id>
  <path>*a other path*</path>
  <title>*a other title*</title>
  <type>**Component**</type>
</doc>
```

But I would like to have something close to that:

```
<doc>
  <id>*an Id*</id>
  <path>*a path*</path>
  <title>*a title*</title>
  <type>**Page**</type>
  <child>
    <id>*an Id*</id>
    <path>*a path*</path>
    <title>*a title*</title>
    <type>**Component**</type>
  </child>
</doc>
```

I'm wondering if it's possible and how can I manage to define my `schema.xml` on that way?

I'm using `Solr 3.6` and I can't change it.

I hope someone can give me a hand.

Regards,
Dekx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solr does not have subdocument structure. However, you can try using multivalued fields to map the content. You can also use delimited values.

***Edit:*** The answer is for Solr v3.6 (as the question is also for v3.6)

as @iMysak mentioned Solr has started supporting nested documents in newer versions (from v4.8 as mentioned [here](http://yonik.com/solr-nested-objects/)).

Comment: I'm not realy trying to have subdocuments. I would like to create something like a field which can contain one or more fields. Is it possible to define a fieldtype "child" who contain fields like id, path and title ?

Comment: Hi, so finaly I used multivalued fields and dynamicField like you said. Thanks.

Comment: just want to mention that at least from 4.8 Solr support parent-child documents - http://yonik.com/solr-4-8-features/

Answer (score 6):

SOLR DOES now (since 4.5?) support/emulate parent/child documents, see example SOLR-schema:

```
<!-- points to the root document of a block of nested documents. Required for nested
document support, may be removed otherwise -->
<field name="_root_" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
```

Even SOLR-J supports adding childDocuments to SolrInputDocument. But it's hard to find any documentation.